# Prove $\frac{\sum_{k=a}^{a+t}\frac{1}{k}}{\sum_{k=b}^{b+t}\frac{1}{k}} \geq \frac{\sum_{k=na}^{na+t}\frac{1}{k}}{\sum_{k=nb}^{nb+t}\frac{1}{k}}$

Tags: inequality

I have tried to prove this for a while, but I cannot get it :(
$$\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=a}^{a+t}\frac{1}{k}}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=b}^{b+t}\frac{1}{k}} \geq \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=na}^{na+t}\frac{1}{k}}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=nb}^{nb+t}\frac{1}{k}} \text{ for all positive integer } a,b,n,t$$

Thanks you !

Answer (score 2):

It’s not true as stated. Let $a=t=1$ and $b=n=2$; then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=a}^{a+t}\frac1k&=\sum_{k=1}^2\frac1k=\frac32\;,\\
\sum_{k=b}^{b+t}\frac1k&=\sum_{k=2}^3\frac1k=\frac56\;,\\
\sum_{k=na}^{na+1}\frac1k&=\sum_{k=2}^3\frac1k=\frac56\;,\text{ and}\\
\sum_{k=nb}^{nb+1}\frac1k&=\sum_{k=4}^5\frac1k=\frac9{20}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\frac{3/2}{5/6}=\frac95<\frac{50}{27}=\frac{5/6}{9/20}\;.$$

Comment: Thanks Brian M. Scott so much, I will check again condition for $n$, then update as soon as possible.

Comment: @VuanCoal: You’re welcome. Leave me a note when you update it; I’m curious to see what it should be.